# print the directory for files in Python

Tags: python, file

```
import os 

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('# I will have a directory here'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print (os.path.join(dirname, filename))
```

It is meant to print the directory for some files in Python. But apart from that I know little... Thanks... There are other pages with the code but it didn't fully explain it in a 'guide for dummies' style.. So I was a little confused. Thanks for your help..:)

Comment: please indent your code. .Explain the part you're trying to achieve in briefly?

Comment: Do you have a specific question about the documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: BREH, go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and then ask this question.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 6):

i'll give it a shot, hope this helps.

```
import os 
#   vvvvvvv directory name of the current position in the walk (eg, /var then /var/log then /var/log/apache2, etc)
#            vvvvvvvv list (array) of sub directories
#                      vvvvvvvvv list (array) of files
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('# I will have a directory here'): # loops through the directories list
    for filename in filenames: #loops through the files returned by the previous for loop
      print (os.path.join(dirname, filename)) # join the directory and the filename returning something like /var/log/dmesg.log
```